# Htaccess redirect https to http for all pages except homepage, redirect https for homepage to another url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I am trying to redirect all https request to http excluding the homepage but i also want the https request for homepage to redirect to another url.

here is what i have in my .htaccess right now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the rule above redirects everything except homepage but i want the homepage redirected to another url e.g

```
https://www.example.com/ 
redirects to
http://www.example.com/non-secured-page
```

i need a full .htaccess rule that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/non-secured-page [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your answer is more accurate. +1

Comment: Thanks @starkeen, only minor differences I guess